# How to redirect 2 different users in different activity after they login?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im creating an application with 2 different users and i want to redirect them in different activity after they login. everytime that you sign up or register in the app. it will ask you if you are student or teacher. after the registration. all information you filled up are stored in firebase database including Name, Phone, Account Type and User Id. This is my code. i hope someone here could help me because this is our thesis project.

This is my LoginActivity.java codes

```
package com.example.vincedamsel.firebase;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextInputLayout emailField;
    private TextInputLayout passwordField;
    private View btnLogin,btnRegister,btnForgotPassword;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private Spinner spinAccountType;
    private DatabaseReference ref;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        emailField = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.email_field);
        passwordField = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.password_field);
        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.login);
        btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.register);
        btnForgotPassword = findViewById(R.id.forgotpassword);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        emailField.requestFocus();

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder2=new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                builder2.setTitle("Register");
                builder2.setMessage("Sign up for Attendance");
                builder2.setPositiveButton("       Professor       ",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        final String type2="Professor";
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Type",type2);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                builder2.setNegativeButton("        Student        ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        final String type1="Student";
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Type",type1);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = builder2.show();
                TextView messageView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                messageView.setTextSize(17);
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!Utils.hasText(emailField)) {
                    Utils.showToast(LoginActivity.this, "Please input your email");
                } else if (!Utils.hasText(passwordField)) {
                    Utils.showToast(LoginActivity.this, "Please input your password");
                } else {
                    //requesting Firebase server
                    showProcessDialog();
                    authenticateUser(Utils.getText(emailField), Utils.getText(passwordField));

                }
            }
        });

        btnForgotPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void authenticateUser(String email, String password) {
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        // When login failed
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Utils.showToast(LoginActivity.this, "Login error!");
                        } else {
                            //When login successful, redirect user to main activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }

    private void showProcessDialog() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Login");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in Firebase server...");
        progressDialog.show();
    }
}
```

[this is my Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i94A.png)

[this is my Rules image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2yUq.png)

Comment: you have problem with app logic not code... try to think harder

Comment: Can you help me please . This is the first time that i use Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

If you want redirect to different activities, you need user type, when user login success, you need retrieve the type of user and redirect to specific activity for example:

```
 String USER_TYPE_1 = "student";
 String USER_TYPE_2 = "profesor";

 /**After login success you add logic:**/

 Intent intent = null;
 if(user.equals(USER_TYPE_1)){
    intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
 }else if(user.equals(USER_TYPE_2)){
    intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
 }

 if(intent!=null){
    startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Remember the user type need retrieve of database or storage whatever you want.

Comment: I dont know how to retrieve the account type of the account that will login in the app. After sign up. The account type info is stored in firebase database. One of the scope of our project is if the professor or teacher forgot their phone. they can borrow a phone to login their account. can you help me please .

Comment: If the user can sign up, the form need ability to select account type, you need account type because if you are login from two different devices, the unique way for know move to respective activity or other conditions  that allows to user show the activity to user that is logging in.

Comment: I add spinner in my login activity but i think it will still login even if i register as student and i login my account and i select teacher or professor in spinner. I dont know how to retrieve the account type in firebase database when i login my account.

Comment: i dont know if firebase have different account types and i don't think is posible add extra attributes to user account, but you can add a Parent User and save extra information of user, after you save the extra information you have the ability to retrieved the information when user attempt to login in your app.

Answer (score 0):

you can use if statement to check account type and use two intents to direct users to the activities

Comment: I want to fetch the account type of the account that i will login in the app. Can you help me. Can you add your idea to my codes so i can try it .

Answer (score -1):

you need to save the status of login type(foe ex:if the student has login u have to save the status as student..if it is professor u have to save it professor)in shared prefernces..at the time of sign up..and at the time of login again u have to fetch the status from shared prefernce by that u can call the activities

Comment: I don't know how shared preference work but what if i sign up in a device but i login in another device. I think i will not login. correct me if i'm wrong.